# How to create search button in visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, datagridview

I already create a form for searching data and fill it in datagridview tools. Then I wanna create a button for searching data by idmember. 
Here screenshot my form:
[image]
Here my code for searching:

```
    Sub CariData()
    With Cari
        Try
            'Dim cari As Integer
            sql = "SELECT * FROM tMember WHERE idmember = '" & .txtcari.Text & "'"
            cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql)
            cmd.Connection = koneksi
            koneksi.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            koneksi.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Pesan Kesalahan")
        End Try
    End With
End Sub
```

And code for calling it:

```
ModuleProses.CariData()
```

But I can search and fill it in datagridview that what I was search, Can someone tell me what I'm wrong? Thanks before.

Comment: Try changing your textbox to a dropdown and have both the member text and memberID as value.

Comment: You desperately need to parameterize you queries. You should NEVER directly execute a string that contains information submitted in a form. Your code is a textbook example of sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: @SeanLange So can you tell me how to create it?

Comment: Tell you how to create what? A parameterized query? Your friend google can handle that. You also should move your Close() to a finally block. As coded, if you encounter an error in your sql your connection is going to be left open. I would also recommend determining which columns you actually need and name them instead of using select *.